# Working with Exponents in c++

Tags: exponential-function

I'm an automotive hobbyist and an intermediate coder. I seem to lack a fundamental understanding of the arithmetic when working with the exponent formula in excel or the math.exp() method in c++.

I have a vendor datasheet which describes a formula to resolve the resistance of a thermistor for any given temperature.

Trying to solve for x, the datasheet gives this: x = exp{A + B/T + C/T2 + D/T3}
where T is the temperature in Kelvin.
note the brackets as opposed to parenthesis.

The datasheet provides values for A, B, & C at various Kelvin ranges

For instance, at 283.15K (50 F), per the datasheet chart;
A is -16.2931
B is 6061.2476
C is -460567.9092
D is 30338541.7656

It doesn't look like a simple matter of (A + B/T + C/T2 + D/T3). Excel's EXP() formula rejects this as too big of a number, running it to a `consol.output(result)` in C++ calls it infinity.  (The brackets {} must mean something other than what parenthesis mean, right?), but what?

How should x be resolved?
Thanks

edit: snapshot of datasheet
[image]

Comment: What are T2,T3,T4? are they $T^2,T^3,T^4$?

Comment: Without the original formula we can't tell if that you have for $x$ is even correct. I doubt the $\{ \cdot \}$ means fractional part, but it's a guess.

Comment: We normally ask people to type in equations here (it generally makes the web site better), but this might be one case where a photo of the data sheet would help.

Comment: It looks like the original equation came from the [Steinhart-Hart formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation) for [4 variables](https://www.northstarsensors.com/calculating-temperature-from-resistance): $$\frac{1}{T} = A+B(\ln(R))+C(\ln(R))^2+D(\ln(R))^3$$ This was then *incorrectly solved* for $R$ (which is $x$ in your case). To actually solve it for $R$, you'll need to use the [Cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) for $\ln(R)$.

Alternatively, use the 3-variable formula recommended on Wikipedia. It also shows a solution for $R$ there.

Comment: @DanielP - That's a heck of a screw-up for a data sheet. Presumably lots of people have used numbers from it before. I agree that that's the thermistor-related equation that most resembles what the OP wrote, which is why I'd love to see the original.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC You're right, that would be a huge messup. But I couldn't find any other equation to calculate / estimate the resistance of a thermistor that resembles the original one this much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I perform the numerical calculation with the proposed coefficients, the result is $2.024$ which is not at all out of range, so the formula may well be the correct one.

My guess would rather be a typo in your written code ?

[Example C++ code](https://tio.run/##hZBdboMwEITfOcUqfeGnAWyDCYFGCnAELkAAtZb4EzEpatWzU5tEgbSV@jTLzDe7MnnXbV/zfJqeWJNXQ1FCmNcZfzsoi8HaM@/LrD4oCms41Blr1EvLCk35VACKdjhVJaTwAnhHTOQGi3kU5hZRE/sErexI2NSmyMSOR1d@LHGH2i71TN/28SpKRERsQnaug0yPuqK2hCMS6ZkX@305durRiKzUiC011VPNSGYVk7baNuK/CrPRte9q@oxlcfVNZF30LR0yODEObcdZzT7KAnRr2cuai/wPyLStdH2OPJ6TmK5GN42vmmi3GzOYtwOHMITN/LaNHMUk5bqnKargN4vvLP6XJXeW/GQF3Jd86BuwA@Vrmr4B)

Comment: This might be it. I did not associate T2 with T squared and T3 with T cubed. I was simply multiplying them (T * 2, etc.) I'll work it out and if it matches the few temps on the datasheet they give,  Ill mark this as the answer.

Comment: This works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the vendor gives for a given range of $T$ the formula
$$x=\exp\Bigg[A+\frac{B}{T}+\frac{C}{T^2}+\frac{D}{T^3}\Bigg]\qquad \text{for} \quad T_1\leq T \leq T_2$$ I stronly suppose that for a given $T$, there is only one $x$.

So, each formula can be analytically inversed for the given range and this has to be done only **once**. So, at each equation corresponds an analytical inverse in the form
$$T=f(x)\qquad \text{for} \quad x_1\leq x \leq x_2$$

Using the second curve as @zwim did, there are three roots but only one is acceptable. Using the trigonometric method with whole numbers and defining
$$p=\frac{29257638226710183955}{1917556492631365761132}$$
$$q=-\frac{1250 }{37923177207}\log
   (x)-\frac{33865607624057288640109707563}{4363190080469560409150476
   13509944}$$ we have
$$ T=\frac 1{2 \sqrt{\frac{p}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3 \sqrt{3} q}{2   p\sqrt p}\right)\right)+\frac{383806591}{75846354414}}$$ for $0.35072 \leq x \leq 3.36287$